# Image cuts only from right when scaling

Tags: html, css, image, centering

Im trying to put this big image centered. Every time I make the image bigger  the window cuts ONLY his right side. It doesn't look centered that way. Also I don't need it in position ABSOLUTE, since I dont want a scroll sideways.

[image]

CSS

```
.container {
padding-top:70px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.slideimg{
display:block;
margin:auto;
height:800px;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<img class="slideimg" src="images/back.jpg" >

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this combination of settings for the image to center it horizontally also if it's wider than the viewport:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Copy the `heigth: 800px;` to the container DIV and define `position: relative;` for the container. Here' the full example:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideimg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 800px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img class="slideimg" src="http://placehold.it/1500x1000/fa0">

</div>
```

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

dont know if this is what you want. take a look.
when you want to center somthing with margin:auto, need to specify width.

```html
<style>
.container {
overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid red;
height:200px;
}

.slideimg{
display:block;
margin:auto;
height:100%;
width:200px;
border:1px solid #CCC;
position:relative;

}

</style>


<div class="container">

<img class="slideimg" src="images/back.jpg" >

</div>
```

Comment: This is the same thing, with different size. My point is: When I scale the image instead of cropping it from both sides, it cuts only its right side